# Multiple Style Attributes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have to apply multiple styles for a element, currently I have

```
document.getElementById("element1").style.top="1px";
document.getElementById("element1").style.marginLeft="0px";
|
|
|
document.getElementById("element1").style.left="10px";
```

How Can I do it in single line ? like

```
document.getElementById("element1").style={"top":"1px","left":"0px"};
```

I want to use plain Javascript not Jquery. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("element1").style.cssText = "top: 1px; left: 0px;";
```

This should work but it would overwrite all existing inline defined styles.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid overwriting your current classes you could do something like the following

`document.getElementById("element1").style.cssText += "top: 1px; left: 0px;";`

Answer (score -1):

1. use JQuery library
2. use css classes

Example:

```
<style>

.someClass {
   top: 1px;
   left: 0px;
}

</style>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#mydiv").addClass("someClass");

  $("#mydiv").removeClass("someClass");

});

</script>

<html>
<body>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Good luck!

Comment: From the question: `I want to use plain Javascript not Jquery`

Comment: Yes, sorry. Read too fast. 
Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript